# How do I fix these errors in c++?

Tags: c++

Please don't hate as I am still learning but I need help sorting the errors to this program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ConCommand.h"

using namespace std;

struct Command
{
    string usage;
    string command;
} command;

void SayCommand(string in)
{
    cout << in.substr(command.length() + 1, in.length()) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string in;
    struct Command command1;

    command1.usage = "say <MESSAGE>";
    command1.command = "say";

    while (true)
    {
        cout << ">>> ";
        getline(cin, in);

        if (in == "")
        {
            cerr << "Please enter a command!" << endl;
        }

        ConCommand(in, command1.usage, command1.command, SayCommand());
    }

    return 0;
}

void ConCommand(string in, string usage, string command, void (*execFunc)(string))
{
    if (in.substr(0, command.length()) == command)
    {
        if (in.substr(command.length(), in.length()) != "")
        {
            //cout << in.substr(command.length() + 1, in.length()) << endl;
            execFunc(in);
        }
        if (in.substr(command.length(), in.length()) == "")
        {
            cout << "Usage: " + usage << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

(The main aim of this program is to create a command line with arguments, but two problems that I have no clue how to fix keep being there = line 15 & line 36.)

Thank you.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] including all of the verbatim error messages you get please.

Comment: Please edit your question with the error text, verbatim.  Don't place into comments.

Comment: Most probable reason for errors is, you don't have a declaration for `void ConCommand(string in, string usage, string command, void (*execFunc)(string));` appearing before `main()`.

Comment: You need an `else` clause after your `if` in the `main` function.  As your code is now, the `ConCommand` function is called whether or not the `in` variable contains a command.

Comment: In your `ConCommand` function, replace the 2nd `if` statement with `else`.

Comment: In your `main` function, how does execution get to the `return` statement?

Comment: If you are not changing a string parameter's content, pass the string by constant reference:  `const std::string &`.  If you are changing the contents, pass by reference:  `std::string &`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error I can see is that you need to move main to the boot of the class.
Thus it will look like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ConCommand.h"

using namespace std;

struct Command
{
   string usage;
   string command;
} command;

void SayCommand(string in)
{
   cout << in.substr(command.length() + 1, in.length()) << endl;
}



void ConCommand(string in, string usage, string command, void (*execFunc)(string))
{
    if (in.substr(0, command.length()) == command)
    {
       if (in.substr(command.length(), in.length()) != "")
       {
           //cout << in.substr(command.length() + 1, in.length()) << endl;
           execFunc(in);
       }
       if (in.substr(command.length(), in.length()) == "")
       {
           cout << "Usage: " + usage << endl;
       }
   }
}

   int main()
{
string in;
struct Command command1;

command1.usage = "say <MESSAGE>";
command1.command = "say";

while (true)
{
    cout << ">>> ";
    getline(cin, in);

    if (in == "")
    {
        cerr << "Please enter a command!" << endl;
    }

    ConCommand(in, command1.usage, command1.command, SayCommand());
}

return 0;
}
```

Also I would recommend being much much more clear. Such that you simplify and tell us what the error that it is giving you is.